# how to fix "Cannot send headers; headers already sent in

Tags: magento-1.9, error

> a:5:{i:0;s:119:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in
>   /home/stepup441/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php,
>   line 60";i:1;s:1029:"#0
>   /home/stepup441/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115):
>   Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

```
1 /home/stepup441/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1265): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
2 /home/stepup441/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
3 /home/stepup441/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
4 /home/stepup441/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
5 /home/stepup441/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
6 /home/stepup441/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
7 /home/stepup441/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You typically get this error if you have echo statements in cron processes which are in cron xml files. The magento cron task process generates this error.

You need to comment out echo statements.

That's as much I can tell you without more detail